# How to customize TTPostController action button

Tags: iphone, ios

Three20 TTPostController has default "Done" button for action. How do I customize the button to e.g "Save"

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "CustomTTPostController.h"
@implementation CustomTTPostController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Save";
}
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Answer containing just code is not very useful. Could you explain the code at least a little bit?

Comment: Override and customize the TTPostController with as much less code as possible.